# asp.net using c# gridview sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a asp.net grid

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GrdUsers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                            Width="95%" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="Black" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" GridLines="Horizontal"
                            CssClass="DataGridStyle" AllowPaging="True" OnRowCommand="GrdUsers_RowCommand"
                            OnRowDeleting="GrdUsers_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GrdUsers_RowEditing" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gridView_Sorting"
                            OnPageIndexChanging="GrdUsers_PageIndexChanging">
                            <%--<EmptyDataRowStyle--%>
                            <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="pgr" />
                            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNorecId" CssClass="notification error" runat="server" Text="No records were found using your search criteria."
                                    Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Brown" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
                            </EmptyDataTemplate>
                            <Columns>
                                <%-- <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="User_Fullname" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="City" DataField="User_city" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="State" DataField="User_state" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Zip" DataField="User_zip" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Joining Date" DataField="User_joiningdate" />--%>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="catId" HeaderText="Categery Id" Visible="False" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="MasterCName" HeaderText="Master Categery" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CatName" HeaderText="Sub Categery" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="GearID" HeaderText="GearID" Visible="False" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="GearName" HeaderText="Gear" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RentHourly" SortExpression="RentHourly">

                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="$"></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RentHourly") %>'></asp:Label>

                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rentdaily" SortExpression="Rentdaily">

                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="$"></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Rentdaily") %>'></asp:Label>

                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RentWeekend" Visible="false">

                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="$" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RentWeekend") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>

                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RentWeekly" Visible="false">

                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="$" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RentWeekly") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>

                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="edit" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GearID") %>'
                                            ImageUrl="~/img/icons/16/edit_icon.png" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDel" runat="server" CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GearID") %>'
                                            ImageUrl="~/img/icons/16/cancel.png" />
                                        <cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="btnDel_ConfirmButtonExtender" runat="server" ConfirmText="Do You  Want To Delete?"
                                            Enabled="True" TargetControlID="btnDel">
                                        </cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <PagerSettings Mode="NextPrevious" NextPageText="Next" PreviousPageText="Last" />
                            <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DBDBDB" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

now i want to sort them renthourly and rentdaily in ascending and descending order

Comment: lolz i post here after 2 hours googleing :-)

Comment: did you checked [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx)?

Comment: You might get more action on this question if you posted some of your attempts at getting the sorting set up, and where you're getting stuck.  The community isn't going to do your work for you.  (at least not for free)

Comment: 'code'                                                       protected void gvServers_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        SortDataAsc(e.SortExpression);
    }
    else if (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Descending)
    {
        SortDataDesc(e.SortExpression);
    }
}'code' i want to know how we will write these functions

Comment: @Ben Please don't post LMGTFY links

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an old question, but your best bet is to use an ObjectDataSource to bind your grid.

Once you use the ObjectDataSource, you can have it automatically supply the SortDirection, SortColumn, CurrentPage and PageSize to the SelectMethod you have specified on the ObjectDataSource.

Inside this business method (your SelectMethod) you can cleanly issue the appropriate command to query only the data needed for the current page and apply the appropriate sorting expression.